# Why is my code doing nothing?

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

When I run the debugger, I get 0 errors, the layout loads, and "Movies" shows up but literally nothing else. I'm fairly new to MVC and some input would be appreciated. The code for the View, Model, and Controller are below. The database contains over 100 items and a list a links is intended to appear but its just white space instead.

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyWebPage.Models.Movie>

     <h1>Movies</h1>
     <ul>
         @foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
         {
          <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Movies", new { id = item.ID })</li>
         }
     </ul>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyWebPage.Models;

namespace MyWebPage.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private MoviesDbContext db = new MoviesDbContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {  

            return View(db.Movies.ToList());
        }

        public ViewResult Movies(int id)
        {
            Movie moviesdb = db.Movie.Find(id);
            return View(moviesdb);
        }

    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyWebPage.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Cover { get; set; }
    }

    public class MoviesDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the database contain any movies?

Comment: looks ok. did u set debugger to confirm db.Movies.ToList() gets rows back?

Comment: What you expect it will happen and what actually see? You don't see the movie list? You click in the list but nothing happen? Be more explicit...

Comment: Stupid question but how do I set the debugger to confirm that it gets rows back?

Comment: set a watch for the variable (lower left usually

Comment: Where do I set the watch, on the line in the view?

Comment: Do you have any custom css? Have you viewed the rendered html in your browser (right click: view source)?

Comment: What would CSS affect and yes. Where the the names should appear is blank.

Comment: Are you sure that you are connecting to the right DB? How is your connection string look like?

Comment: <add name="MoviesDbContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Movies;Integrated Security=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Its not a problem that my database is .mdf and not .sdf right?